# If a FIND fails to find input VBA6

Tags: excel, vba

It has just dawned on me What if the user puts in something not in the database (excel spreadsheet)? I have poured over all these posted fixes and none seem to meet my needs. Would someone look over my code Please.

```
Private Sub OkayCommandButton_Click()
Worksheets("Parts List").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A2").Select
PN = PartNumber.Value
KN = KanbanNumber.Value
If ((PartNumber = vbNullString) And (KanbanNumber = vbNullString)) Then
   ' Both textboxes are empty, message box opened and focus to part number
   MsgBox "Please enter a Part Number or Kanban Number"
   PartNumber.SetFocus
Else
   ' One or more textboxes contain a search string
    If Not (PartNumber = vbNullString) Then
       'Part number is given, run search
       Cells.find(What:=PN, After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Else
   ' Part Number is not given
   ' Since we checked that at least one textbox contains text
   ' the Kanban Number must be set if Part Number has not been set
       Cells.find(What:=KN, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End If
End If
PartInformation.Caption = _
"Part Number" & vbTab & ActiveCell & vbCrLf & _
"Kanban" & vbTab & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 45) & vbCrLf & _
"Part Name" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & vbCrLf & _
"Supplier" & vbTab & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) & vbCrLf & _
"Next Process" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) & vbCrLf & _
"Qty in Tote" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 44) & vbCrLf & _
"PC Location" & vbTab & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 46)
PartInformation1.Caption = "Line    " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
End Sub
```

Comment: `What:=PN`??? Should it not be `What:=PartNumber.text` and similarly for the other? Also your `Cells()` and `Range()` will refer to the `ActiveSheet`. It is advisable to fully qualify them. The `ActiveSheet` may not be the sheet that you think it is...

Comment: Siddharth, Sorry for the confusion. I have put the whole code in. Would you take a look now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for [Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839746.aspx) is that it returns `Nothing` if the search term doesn't exist in the searched area. `Nothing` is a special value which you can test for.

To deal with search terms which don't exist, try adding `Dim rFindResult As Range` immediately after the `Private Sub...` line and then alter the Cells.Find statements like this:

```
Set rFindResult = Cells.Find(What:=KN, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If (rFindResult Is Nothing) Then
    ` display MesgBox, reset focus appropriately, exit sub
Else
    rFindResult.Activate
End If
```

Siddarth Rout's point about specifying which sheet to use rather than implicitly relying on the active sheet is well worth heeding. Also, in the case where neither part number nor kanban number is specified, there should probably be an `Exit Sub` after setting the focus to part number

Comment: barrow... Thanks for the code. I have tried it and it does not work. I moved the If (rFindResult Is Nothing) Then statement to below the Set rFindResults and above the PartInformation.Caption. I get no object. I also can not step thru the code. It also gives me information from the active cell on the UserForm. What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got it to work!!!! Thanks for your help ! Really you don't know how much this has helped me. Appreciate the time you took to explain.